# How can I localise colorbox?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, localization, coffeescript, colorbox

I installed Colorbox in my ROR application. But I need localisation. In the script i have:

file images.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
          $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1',
 transition:"none", maxWidth:"85%", maxHeight:"85%",
 current: "{current} <%= t('views.image.of') %> {total}"})
```

where {current} is current image and {total} are total images.

How to paste data from yml-file (app/config/locales/**.yml)?

Comment: I tried "{current} t('views.image.of') {total}" and "{current}" + t('views.image.of') + "{total}" and "{current} i18n.t('views.image.of') {total}" and "{current}" + i18n.t('views.image.of') + "{total}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use gem
https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js

It's works!

```
$(document).ready ->
      $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1',
          transition:"none", maxWidth:"85%", maxHeight:"85%",
           current: "{current} <%= I18n.t('views.image.of') %> {total}"})
```

Answer (score 7):

You are translating a jQuery plugin. Do it within the `vendor` directory, not in your application locales.

jQuery ColorBox maintains a `i18n` directory with translations:
https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/tree/master/i18n

Example

```
/*
  jQuery ColorBox language configuration
    language: Spanish (es)
    translated by: migolo
*/
jQuery.extend(jQuery.colorbox.settings, {
    current: "Imagen {current} de {total}",
    previous: "Anterior",
    next: "Siguiente",
    close: "Cerrar",
    xhrError: "Error en la carga del contenido.",
    imgError: "Error en la carga de la imagen."
});
```

You can download one and include it after colorbox (bonus points if you use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)).

*Example with `Rails >= 3.1`*

```
//= require jquery.colorbox
//= require jquery.colorbox-es
```